# Clarification on asymptotically stability of dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I'm wondering if someone can provide a clarification between 2 seemingly opposing definitions from reputable sources on dynamical systems!

My Russian textbook, "Dynamical Systems I: Ordinary Differential Equations and Smooth Dynamical Systems" by Anosov, Arnol'd, Aronson, et al., says the following to determine whether a singular point of a dynamical system is **asymptotically stable**:

> Theorem 4.2: If all eigenvalues of the linear part of a vector field $v$ at a singular point have negative real part, then the singular point is asymptotically stable.

To me, this means for any arbitrary dynamical system, say, $\dot{x} = f(x)$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, one can find where $f(x) = 0$, and solve the corresponding Jacobian for the eigenvalues of to determine stability. Further, if one finds that $\lambda_{i} < 0$, for $i = 1,2,...n$ then, this point is locally stable, by this theorem.  But, is this theorem now suggesting that this is point is now asymptotically stable as well?

Almost every single textbook on ODEs that I have checked says to determine whether an equilibrium point is asymptotically stable, some more general method is required like constructing Lyapunov functions, determining limit sets, etc...

Why is there such a difference? Is there a difference?

Comment: You might not have enough regularity to linearize. Your limit set might not be a point. The eigenvalues might be too hard to calculate.

Comment: Theorem 4.2 gives a sufficient condition for asymptotic stability not necessary. Consider for example the simple first order system $\dot{x}=-x^3$ which is asymptotically stable but fails to meet conditions of the Theorem.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I thought of that example too. So, this seems to be a "shortcut" theorem, that avoids the use of Lyapunov functions, etc... when they can be avoided?

Comment: Yes, it is called the first Lyapunov theorem.

Comment: Okay! So, does theorem 4.2 above also refer to globally stable as well? I.e., does globally and asymptotically stable mean the same thing in this context? Thanks.

Comment: No it refers to local asymptotic stability only. Think of $\dot{x}=-x+x^3$..

Comment: What is the difference between local asymptotically stable, asymptotically stable, and globally asymptotically stable?

Comment: Oh, and another problem: the linearization could have eigenvalues with zero real part, in which case you can still have asymptotic stability. CTNT's $x'=-x^3$ example is of this type. So if *all* of them have negative real part, then you have asymptotic stability, and if *one* of them has positive real part, then you don't. But if some eigenvalues have negative real part and the others have zero real part, then neither of these conditions is satisfied and it could go either way.

Comment: Ahh yes, didn't think of that. Thanks Ian.

Comment: Asymptotic stability=(Lyapunov stability)+(convergence to the singular point). Local asymptotic stability means that there exists a region around the equilibrium s.t. the above two properties hold true for perturbations within this region. Global means that they hold for arbitrarily large perturbations.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for your answers and clarifications, it is much appreciated...

Comment: You are welcome, Thomas!

Comment: $\lambda_i<0$ for all $i=1,\,2,\,\dots,\,n$ shows asymptotic stability (locally). The theorem from the Russian textbook is a theorem  only for local asymptotic stability (negative eigenvalues) and instability (positive eigenvalues). If any $\lambda_i$ is zero, there can nothing said about the equilibrium. The theorem also similar to the indirect method of Lyapunov.